# Take bash startup file(s) with you into ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

Is it possible to "bring with you" a copy of bash_profile from the source machine when doing an ssh to remote? And maybe even automatically source it right after login? If so, how can I do this? I can probably imagine some really elaborate shell hack (unless this is somehow restricted due to security concerns), but maybe there's a nice and clean way.

Comment: Please have look at: [SF: How to use a custom .bashrc file on SSH login](https://serverfault.com/questions/400522)  [SU: loading local shell aliases to ssh session dynamicaly](https://superuser.com/q/503784) Be aware that some settings in your bash_profile or alike might not work or cripple the local setup (eg invalid `PATH`, unknown binaries in functions, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my `~/.ssh/config` I have an entry to choose the remote session file to use when log on in a server. In my case I use a specific `rc` file instead of `.bashrc`.

```
Host *
LocalCommand scp ~/.remote_bashrc %r@%n:/home/%r
RemoteCommand bash --rcfile "~/.remote_bashrc"
```

First, one copies the file to the remote.

Second, one uses it as shell session configuration.

Comment: Can you please clarify what `%r@%n:/home/%r` means?

Comment: `man ssh_config`: `%r    The remote username, %n    The original remote hostname, as given on the command line.` I copy the file to my homedir (`/home/my_name`) in the remote host.

Comment: Needed to add `PermitLocalCommand yes`.